# How to get and compare the time with Pebble JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

This sounds really obvious but I actually cannot find a time variable or something. I want to create a school timetable app for my pebble but I can't find the reference or variable that tells me this info. I would expect something that would end up like (Python because I know it better and don't want to use JS right now):

```
if (hour == 10) and (minute == 03):
  print("Next Lesson!")
```

So what are the variable name for these??? A link of all of them in Pebble would be good if that exists but I can't find it in the documentation.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. Please tell me I don't have to learn C just to write this...

Comment: something like this https://pebble.github.io/pebblejs/#clock??

Comment: Close, but just the time, not the seconds since the epoch. Though it could work if nothing else does.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that doing a google search.... probably should put a little more research in

Comment: What did you search?

Comment: pebble js, then looked at the api documentation